# Uniform lower bound of the inner product of two positively correlated random variables

Tags: probability, inner-products, upper-lower-bounds, correlation

Suppose $W$ is a mean-zero random variable with unit variance, i.e., $E(W)=0,Var(W)=1$. Let $g(\cdot)$ be a non-constant increacing function such that $g(W)$ has zero mean and variance $\epsilon>0$, i.e., $E(g(W))=0,Var(g(W))\ge\epsilon$. Can we have a non-zero lower bound on $E\{g(W)W\}$ uniformly for all such $g$? Or equivalently, does there exist some positive constant $c>0$ such that $E\{g(W)W\}>c$ hold for all such $g$?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. See the example from this [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566315/what-is-the-correlation-between-a-random-variable-and-its-probability-integral-t)

Comment: Thanks for the sharing!